# Mongoose - Bun - Elysia - Mongo TCP Socket Issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bun, elysiajs

I need help with this issue: Mongo Socket continuously closes connection, so, I’m assuming the keepAlive socket property isn’t working as it should.

`error: connection 2 to host:27017 closed`

Mongoose 8.2.0

Bun 1.0.28

Elysia 0.8.17

I temporarily fixed this by reading anything from DB every 30 seconds, although it may not be the best solution for a Atlas Serverless solution given that every read costs.

`setInterval(async () => await App.findById("anything"), 30000)`

Thanks

Additional info: I use the same Mongo user and password to connect from two different backend servers (I don't know if this could be a problem)

Comment: That is what tcp_keepalive is for, are you setting that on the client side?